# Get pairs of keys and values from the Json, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, dhtmlx

I'm a bit stuck on how to get the keys and values from the given Json and assign it to another javascript function. The idea is that user select a value from the select list and the code should loop through the Json, find particular keys and values (based on what user have chosen) and push this keys and values into another javascript constructor to draw a chart. Here is so far what I was able to do: html select list with fire up function onclick event:

```
<select id="abc">
 <option value="v1" onclick="my_function()">V1</option>
</select>
```

And here is a function that should do the rest. However, when I loop through the Json, ONLY the last pair assigned to the js constructor and therefore ONLY one (last) pair is visible on the screen. How to assign ALL keys and values into constructor? Here is my code so far:

```
function my_function(){
var my_element = document.getElementById("abc").value;  // get the select list value                                                            
var arr=[''];                                                                                                               
var j=0;
for (var i = 0; i < json_name.data.length; i++) {       // start the  loop
 if($.inArray(json_name.data[i][my_element],arr)<0){                                                                                
  arr[j]=json_name.data[i][my_element];                

 gantt.groupBy({                                       // here is constructor starts
 relation_property: my_element,                                                 
groups:   [{                                                                                
    key: arr[j], label: arr[j] }],                                                                              
    group_id: "key",
    group_text: "label"
});
  j++; 
}}
}
```

And here is a sample of Json:

```
var json_name = {
        "data":[
            {"id":11, "text":"Project #1", "start_date":"", "duration":"", "progress": 0.6, "open": true},
            {"id":12, "text":"Task #1", "start_date":"03-04-2013", "duration":"5", "parent":"11", "progress": 1, "open": true},
            {"id":13, "text":"Task #2", "start_date":"", "duration":"", "parent":"11", "progress": 0.5, "open": true},
            {"id":14, "text":"Task #3", "start_date":"02-04-2013", "duration":"6", "parent":"11", "progress": 0.8, "open": true},
            {"id":15, "text":"Task #4", "start_date":"", "duration":"", "parent":"11", "progress": 0.2, "open": true},
            {"id":16, "text":"Task #5", "start_date":"02-04-2013", "duration":"7", "parent":"11", "progress": 0, "open": true},
            {"id":17, "text":"Task #2.1", "start_date":"03-04-2013", "duration":"2", "parent":"13", "progress": 1, "open": true}];}
```

Can anyone point me how to get all keys and values and assign them in the constructor? e.g. lets say user select the Duration from the select list, so code should loop through the whole json, fetch all Duration keys and values and push them all into constructor? So in my understanding, constructor should look like this:

```
gantt.groupBy({
relation_property: my_element,                                                                      
groups: [{
    key:1, label:1},{                                 // where key and a label equals to first matched key and value in json                                                        
    key:2, label: 2},{   
 ......                                               // second matched etc etc
    key:7, label: 7} ],                               // last matched key and value ..
group_id: "key",
group_text: "label"
});
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you call gantt.groupBy on each iteration always providing it with only one item:

```
gantt.groupBy({  // here is constructor starts
 relation_property: my_element,                                                 
groups:   [{                                                                                
    key: arr[j], label: arr[j] }],       // only one item in groups array                                                                       
    group_id: "key",
    group_text: "label"
});
```

what you need to do is

1. collect an array of all groups
2. pass them all into gantt.groupBy

Although, I don't quite understand what exactly your filter does. I.e. from your sample:

```
var my_element = document.getElementById("abc").value; // my_element = "v1" for a given sample
```

and later in code:

```
if($.inArray(json_name.data[i][my_element],arr)<0){
```

for this sample **json_name.data[i][my_element]** is equivalent to **json_name.data[i]["v1"]** - and if I'm not missing anything, it will always be undefined since objects in your sample json doesn't have 'v1' property.

Am I missing something, or is something missing from your code/json sample?

btw, if you tracking user input on select control, a more reliable way is to capture 'change' event on select node rather than 'click' on each option, since one can change select value not only from mouse but from the keyboard as well

```
<select id="abc" onchange="my_function()">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

**UPDATE**

I guess something following should do:
html:

```
<select onchange="groupByProperty(this.value)">
    <option value="" selected>none</option>
    <option value="duration">duration</option>
    <option value="progress">progress</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
//get array of groups that can be provided to gantt.groupBy from array of tasks and property name
function groupsFromProperty(tasks, propertyName){

    // get unique values of the property
    var groupKeys = tasks.reduce( function(hash, currentItem) {
        hash[currentItem[propertyName]] = true;
        return hash;
    }, {});

    // form an array of {key:,label:} objects from unique values
    var groups = [];
    for(var i in groupKeys){
        groups.push({key: i, label:i});
    }

    return groups;
}

function groupByProperty(propertyName){
    if(propertyName){
        gantt.groupBy({
            groups: groupsFromProperty(gantt.getTaskByTime(), propertyName),
            relation_property: propertyName,
            group_id: "key",
            group_text: "label"
        });
    }else{
        gantt.groupBy(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Alex Klimenkov Thanks for the comment Alex. The v1 is just a dummy example, on the real select item should be one of the existing properties presented on the json (e.g. 'progress', 'duration' etc .. ). The 'onchange' doesn't work for some reasons that's why I've changed it to 'onclick' which works fine. But this is minor issues and easily can be fixed. The more important question is how to attach each pair (key and label) to the gantt.groupBy ? Can you provide some example please? Not a huge fan of js .. lol Thanks

Comment: Thanks Alex, works like a charm. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot !